# Training and Testing Datasets for Art

Tags: dataset, neural-network, tensorflow, classification, conv-neural-network

I am attempting to make a classification NN to classify what type of art a certain piece (modern, contemporary, etc) but I don't know of any training and Testing data sets. Would the art category on ImageNet suffice? **Do you know of any data sets with works of art along with some indication of what type/style they are (i.e. modern, contemporary, etc)?**

Comment: have you made any progress here? Have you found and trg data? If yes, could you share the source?

Comment: @zinyosrim No I didn't look particularly hard. The best idea I had was to scrape the Metropolitan Museum of Art's online database but I never actually implemented it.